# Repeat mode doesn't repeat, how to debug?

Tags: emacs28

`repeat-mode` is completely failing to operate as advertised. I get the message saying it's enabled, and thereafter Emacs carries on exactly as if it has *not* been enabled, with supposed command-repeating keys instead being inserted into the buffer. In other words, I have never seen repeat mode work. No error messages appear. How might I go about debugging this?

Example sequence:

- Split a frame into two or more windows
- `M-x repeat-mode` (I have it on `C-R`). The "mode enabled" message appears.
- `C-x o` switches buffer as expected.
- `o` (or uppercase `O`) is inserted instead of repeating `switch-buffer`. No error, no debugger with `toggle-debug-on-error`.
- `M-x repeat-mode`. The "mode disabled" message appears.

Ditto for the window-resizing suite of commands.

`M-x describe-repeat-maps` shows the window movement and resizing suites plus several others as expected. But no!

Emacs 28.1 with native comp, Manjaro, StumpWM.

Comment: It works for me. The message I get when I enable it is `Repeat mode is enabled for 23 commands and 9 keymaps; see ‘describe-repeat-maps’`. Try doing `M-x describe-repeat-maps` and seeing if `other-window` is in there? Emacs 29.0.50 built about two months ago from git.

Comment: Did you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, try that. If no problem that way, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @NickD edited question in response to add already-taken step

Comment: @Drew Of course I should have done that first and of course it works with `emacs -Q`, blast it. Unfortunately my config is simply too complex to bisect, a web of interlocking autoloads in 96 files. Anyway, it's obviously my problem to solve alone. I was hoping somebody knew the mechanism that `repeat-mode` uses to intercept keystrokes. Thanks for your help anyway guys. I'll leave this up for a while in case I come up with a solution. In the meantime, it's back to `C-x z` for me.

Comment: I'd still suggest some form of bisecting your init file. After all, all you're trying to test is whether `repeat-mode` works. Surely you can load *some* subset of your setup and check that, to at least narrow the search space somewhat. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I'll second that: trying to run `edebug` was an utter failure; `repeat.el` uses variables from the command-loop, like `this-command`, `last-command` and `last-command-event` that can change under your feet when you are debugging. It's like trying to dissect  a squirming, slippery fish :-)